# XmlDocument - SelectSingleNode with namespace

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlPath);
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(reader);
XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;

XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode("marketingid");
```

XML that works:

```
<confirmsubmit>
    <marketingid>-1</marketingid>
</confirmsubmit>
```

XML that doesn't work:

```
<confirmsubmit xmlns="http:....">
    <marketingid>-1</marketingid>
</confirmsubmit>
```

What is the way to deal with the xmlns attribute and how can i parse it?

Is it has anything to do with namespace?

**EDIT:**
This is the code that works:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlPath);
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(reader);

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", xmlDoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);

XmlNode book = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/ns:confirmsubmit/ns:marketingid", nsmgr);
```

This all XPath is more complicated than seems, I would recommand to begginers like my to read: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: Yes! ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.addnamespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add a XmlNamespaceManager instance in the game, as shown in this example from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bektfx9(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ```
> public class Sample
> {
>     public static void Main()
>     {
>
>       XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
>       doc.Load("booksort.xml");
>
>       //Create an XmlNamespaceManager for resolving namespaces.
>       XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
>       nsmgr.AddNamespace("bk", "urn:samples");
>
>       //Select and display the value of all the ISBN attributes.
>       XmlNodeList nodeList;
>       XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
>       nodeList = root.SelectNodes("/bookstore/book/@bk:ISBN", nsmgr);
>       foreach (XmlNode isbn in nodeList){
>         Console.WriteLine(isbn.Value);
>       }
>
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it from LINQ to XML. Short and simple

```
const string xml = @"<confirmsubmit xmlns='http:....'>
                       <marketingid>-1</marketingid>
                     </confirmsubmit>";

XElement element = XElement.Parse(xml);
var requestedElement = element.Elements().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName.Equals("marketingid"));
```

Answer (score -2):

`xmlns` attribute is used at XHTML and defines namespace for a document. You can parse it like:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
var attrib = xdoc.Root.Attribute("xmlns").Value;
```