# How to get list of values when XML contains many namespaces

Tags: c#, xpath

I have following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<cincinnati xmlns="http://www.sesame-street.com/abc/def/1">
  <cincinnatiChild xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ElementValue xmlns:a="http://schemas.data.org/2004/07/sesame-street.abc.def.ghi">
      <a:someField>false</a:someField>
      <a:data xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <b:KeyValueThing>
          <b:Key>key1</b:Key>
          <b:Value i:type="a:ArrayOfPeople">
            <a:Person>
              <a:firstField>
              </a:firstField>
              <a:dictionary>
                <b:KeyValueThing>
                  <b:Key>ID</b:Key>
                  <b:Value i:type="c:long" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">000101</b:Value>
                </b:KeyValueThing>
                <b:KeyValueThing>
                  <b:Key>Name</b:Key>
                  <b:Value i:type="c:string" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">John</b:Value>
                </b:KeyValueThing>
              </a:dictionary>
            </a:Person>
            <a:Person>
            ...
                  <b:Value i:type="c:long" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">000102</b:Value>
            ...
            </a:Person>
          </b:Value>
        </b:KeyValueThing>
      </a:data>
    </ElementValue>
  </cincinnatiChild>
</cincinnati>
```

I need to get a list if ID values, e.g. `000101, 000102...`.

I think using XPath makes sense here but the multitude of namespaces makes it confusing (so a simple `XmlNamespaceManager` won't do).

Basically I need something like this (this syntax is of course not correct):

```
XmlDocument doc = // Load the xml
doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/cincinati/cincinnatiChild/ElementValue/a:data/b:KeyValueThing/b:Value/a:Person/a:dictionary[b:KeyValueThing/b:Key='ID']");
```

also when I do `doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/cincinnati")` or `doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/cincinnatiChild")` I get `null`.

Since I'm unsure how to piece together al the helpfull advice from the comments I would like to see a working `c#` code line, either `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` are OK.

I also tries this before the `SelectSingleNode`:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("a", "http://schemas.data.org/2004/07/sesame-street.abc.def.ghi");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("b", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("c", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("i", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("d", "http://www.sesame-street.com/abc/def/1");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XmlDocument - SelectSingleNode with namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535102/xmldocument-selectsinglenode-with-namespace)

Comment: Every node here belongs to a namespace, starting with `cincinnati` that belongs to `http://www.sesame-street.com/abc/def/1`. Selecting just `cincinnati` will correctly give null.

Comment: `multitude of namespaces makes it confusing (so a simple XmlNamespaceManager won't do)` - why wouldn't XmlNamespaceManager do?

Comment: @GSerg - I dont' know how to use a simple XmlNamespaceManager since there are many namespaces

Comment: Provide a [mre], and do NOT use "..." just before the second value that you want to be returned.

Comment: @grunt So call `AddNamespace` many times and not just one?

Comment: Try: `xmlstarlet sel -N i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" -N a="http://schemas.data.org/2004/07/sesame-street.abc.def.ghi" -N b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" -t -m "//b:Key" -i ".='ID'" -v ../b:Value -b -n input.xml`, using [tag:xmlstarlet]

Comment: you could even add `-C` to the above, to show the used: XSLT.

Comment: "multitude of namespaces" - like 3. Too much to handle.

Comment: @GSerg - I tried adding many times. I may not be doing it correctly.

Comment: The default namespace `xmlns="http://www.sesame-street.com/abc/def/1"` has the prefix `d`, so your XPath must be `/d:cincinnati/d:cincinnatiChild/...`. If you don't use a prefix, it's looking for a node without namespace - which doesn't exist.

Comment: this xpath may help! `var node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/d:cincinnati/d:cincinnatiChild/d:ElementValue/a:data/b:KeyValueThing/b:Value/a:Person/a:dictionary[b:KeyValueThing/b:Key='ID']", nsmgr);`

Answer (score 0):

You could bypass the namespace issues using the local-name()-function.

i.e.: in stead of `b:KeyValueThing` use `*[local-name()='KeyValueThing']`

a simple global XPath could look like this:

```
//*[local-name()='KeyValueThing'][*[local-name()='Key' and text()='ID' ]]/*[local-name()='Value']/text()
```

If you want to be more precise and speed up the XPath it would look like this:

```
/*[local-name()='cincinnati']/*[local-name()='cincinnatiChild']/*[local-name()='ElementValue']/*[local-name()='data']/*[local-name()='KeyValueThing']/*[local-name()='Value']/*[local-name()='Person']/*[local-name()='dictionary']/*[local-name()='KeyValueThing'][*[local-name()='Key' and text()='ID' ]]/*[local-name()='Value']/text()
```

Comment: Does this answers your question?